# Is it possible run syslog inside Docker and expose that to the host as host's syslog daemon?

Tags: docker, syslog

I am trying to run syslog inside Docker so that it has access to DNS configuration for the container. Is it possible run syslog inside Docker and expose that to the host as host's syslog daemon?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I'm doing this at the moment, because I've got a containerised ELK (Elasticsearch/Logstash/Kibana).

My logstash runs a listener on port 514 for syslog traffic* which it forwards to ELK.

Well, more correctly - I'm running a haproxy instance, that I'm redirecting using confd and etcd to wherever my syslog container is, but the principle stands.

My hosts have

```
*.* @@localhost
```

in their `rsyslog.conf`

And it works nicely. (and I can also log from my containers to this syslogd)

Answer (score 0):

I think this a bit old but it can help others!

I think the best way is to use docker driver to send logs to syslog instead of running syslog inside. 
One of the best practices in docker is to run only one process inside the container.

If you would like to have one docker running syslog inside and forward all logs to this container from other containers this will be good idea, because you will separate concerns and also you can scale the log container.

Here is a container that do that: [enter link description here](https://github.com/gliderlabs/logspout)